# State store not getting updated properly in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and trying to use Redux in my React App.

Here are my Reducers.

The roor reducer -

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import dataListReducer from './dataList';

export default combineReducers({
    dataListReducer
})
```

and dataList reducer-

```
const INITITAL_STATE={gridData:[]}

const dataListReducer=(state=INITITAL_STATE,action)=>{    
switch(action.type){
    default: return {...state}
}
return state;
}

export default dataListReducer;
```

Here is the action creator class -

```
export const dataLoaded=(data)=>{
    return {
        type:'full_data',
         payload:{gridData:data}
    }
}
```

Now from the below component I am making a Fetch call to the network and when the call returns I want to update the application state with the latest data -

```
 componentDidMount()
{
  FetchService(this.state.url)
    .then((res)=> res.json())
    .then(  (result)=>this.updateState(result)                                   
         ).catch(function(error){console.log(error)});
}


updateState(result)
{
  this.props.dataLoaded(result);  
}
```

The component is making a call to connect as prescribed -

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{  
  console.log(state);
return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{dataLoaded})(Main)
```

Why does the console.log does not print the latest data?

What am I missing here?

Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done in your reducer is to return the same state it already has. So it's a void reducer - like doing no action. What you need to do is when returning from the reducer, to actually take into account what is passed in action's payload.

`case "full_data":
       return { ...state, action.payload }`

or I would even suggest to specify explicitly the property, so that further extensions will be possible and will not override any siblings

`case "full_data":
       return { ...state, ...gridData: action.payload.gridData }`

Comment: makes sense. But why this line shows error (Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ",")         return { ...state, action.payload }

Comment: In the example I am using the [spread](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754?gi=ae6d2c1db81c) operator, which is a feature of ES6. You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead if you are using an older JS version.

Answer (score 1):

Friend, you have not defined anything in your reducer to process actions that are dispatched to it.

To do that you need to set up some cases in your reducer like this:

```
const dataListReducer=(state=INITITAL_STATE,action)=>{    
    switch(action.type){
       case "full_data":
          return {...state, myData}
       default: 
          return state
}
```

That way your reducer will update when an action is dispatched to it.

Comment: I have a defult in the switch which copies the state to a new object and returns it. It should have worked right?

Comment: It works, but it sets the same state as it previously had -- no update. You should instead set the date from the payload in the state, so that you can see the actual UI update.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
const INITITAL_STATE={gridData:[]}

const dataListReducer=(state=INITITAL_STATE,action)=>{    
  switch(action.type){
      case: 'full_data':
        return { ...state, gridData: action.payload.gridData }
      default: return {...state}
  }
}

export default dataListReducer;
```